# Mysql summary query with date range, multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Im running a sql query that is returning results between dates I have selected (2012-07-01 - 2012-08-01). I can tell from the values they are wrong though.

Im confused cause its not telling me I have a syntax error but the values returned are wrong.

The dates in my database are stored in the date column in the format YYYY-mm-dd.

```
SELECT `jockeys`.`JockeyInitials` AS `Initials`, `jockeys`.`JockeySurName` AS Lastname`,
       COUNT(`runs`.`JockeysID`) AS 'Rides', 
       COUNT(CASE
                  WHEN `runs`.`Finish` = 1 THEN 1 
                  ELSE NULL 
             END
             ) AS  `Wins`, 
        SUM(`runs`.`StakeWon`) AS 'Winnings'
  FROM runs
 INNER JOIN jockeys ON runs.JockeysID = jockeys.JockeysID
 INNER JOIN races ON runs.RacesID = races.RacesID
 WHERE `races`.`RaceDate` >= STR_TO_DATE('2012,07,01', '%Y,%m,%d')
   AND `races`.`RaceDate` <= STR_TO_DATE('2012,08,01', '%Y,%m,%d')
 GROUP BY `jockeys`.`JockeySurName` 
 ORDER BY `Wins` DESC`
```

Comment: What type is RaceDate?  If it's a DATE field, why not just use `'2012-07-01'` and `'2012-08-01'` as your comparison strings?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You say "the values returned are wrong." It will be easier to help you if you tell us what's wrong with those values.

Comment: If I try `STR_TO_DATE('2012-07-01', '%Y-%m-%d')` I get a syntax error - "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`, COUNT(`runs`.`JockeysID`) AS 'Rides', COUNT(CASE ' at line 1". @Ollie Jones it returns far more results than is possible if it were getting the date range I selected.

Comment: I didn't say use `STR_TO_DATE()`, I just said use `'2012-07-01'` and `'2012-08-01'` as your comparison **strings**.  You don't have to use `STR_TO_DATE()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to guess what the problem is from your question.

Are you looking to summarize all the races in July and the races on the first of August? That's a slightly strange date range.

You should try the following kind of date-range selection if you want to be more precise. You MUST use it if your races.RaceDate column is a DATETIME expression.

```
 WHERE `races`.`RaceDate` >= STR_TO_DATE('2012,07,01', '%Y,%m,%d')
   AND `races`.`RaceDate` <  STR_TO_DATE('2012,08,01', '%Y,%m,%d') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

This will pick up the July races and the races at any time on the first of August.

But, it's possible you're looking for just the July races.  In that case you might try:

```
 WHERE `races`.`RaceDate` >= STR_TO_DATE('2012,07,01', '%Y,%m,%d')
   AND `races`.`RaceDate` <  STR_TO_DATE('2012,07,01', '%Y,%m,%d') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

That will pick up everything from midnight July 1, inclusive, to midnight August 1 exclusive.

Also, you're not using `GROUP BY` correctly. When you summarize, every column in your result set must either be a summary (`SUM()` or `COUNT()` or some other aggregate function) or mentioned in your GROUP BY clause.  Some DBMSs enforce this. MySQL just rolls with it and gives strange results.  Try this expression.

```
GROUP BY `jockeys`.`JockeyInitials`,`jockeys`.`JockeySurName`
```

Comment: I was really just testing it out so the date is just a random range. I just want it to display the correct data.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the jocky surnames are not unique.  Try changing the group by expression to:

```
group by `jockeys`.`JockeyInitials`, `jockeys`.`JockeySurName`
```

In general, it is bad practice to include columns in the `SELECT` clause of an aggregation query that are not included in the `GROUP BY` line.  You can do this in MySQL (but not in other databases), because of a (mis)feature called Hidden Columns.

Comment: Thanks for the advice wrt bad practices. When I try AS `Initials` I get a syntax error. #1064 - near 'AS `Initials` , `jockeys`.`JockeySurName` ORDER BY `Wins` DESC , `Winnings` ' at line 12